# Why is ASP.NET MVC 3 not validating my floats correctly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a View where I allow input, the fields are set as float in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database and I am using Entity Framwork 4.

In the Entity Framework Model the field looks like this `private Nullable<global::System.Double> _TestNumber;`

And the View uses an EditorField to allow input like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestNumber)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestNumber)
</div>
```

I am however getting this error in the Validation Message: `The value '13.51' is not valid for TestNumber.` I've tried with a comma instead of period, same thing.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public double? TestNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel { TestNumber = 13.51 });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TestNumber)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TestNumber)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

One thing that you could checkout and which could explain the behavior you are observing is inconsistency between client side culture and server side culture. So for example if you have enabled client-side validation but the client culture uses `,` as decimal separator then `13.51` will fail client-side validation and if the server culture uses `.` as decimal separator then `13,51` would fail server side validation. So both `13.51` and `13,51` are failing to validate but on different layers. In order for the server to use the same culture as the client you could set the following the culture to `auto` in your web.config:

```
<globalization 
    requestEncoding="utf-8" 
    responseEncoding="utf-8" 
    culture="auto" 
    uiCulture="auto"
/>
```

Comment: I've added that globalization in `<system.web>` but as soon as I submit the form it says `The value '10.50' is not valid for`. How do I ensure that it really is the same culture now?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, what about `10,50`?

Comment: That works when I set ClientValidationEnabled to false `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/> ` but not when it is set to true.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, it works for me when I set the culture to `auto` in web.config. For example I have my browser configured to use en-US culture and the server configured to use fr-FR culture. Validation fails in all cases. When I set the server culture to auto (meaning that it uses the same as the client) validation passes.

Comment: And you have ClientValidationEnabled set to True in Web.Config? It's really weird. What MVC 3 version are you running RC 2?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, yes ClientValidationEnabled is set to true. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM.

Comment: That might be why it doesnt work then. I am on RC 2, didn't know there was an RTM!

Comment: Doesn't work with the RTM either! I wonder what else it could be? I've got the input page in an Area, and I've got the globalization in that web.config aswell.

Comment: @Filip, that's strange. What is the culture you are using on the server and on the client? Try manually setting it to some value and see if it works.

Comment: @Darin, I am in Sweden so sv-SE I guess. Do I need to change it anywhere else than `culture="sv-SE"` and `uiculture="sv-SE"` ?

Comment: @Filip, no that's what is used by the model binder on the server and that should be enough. How about the browser?

Comment: How can I see that in Chrome? I only find encoding and that's set to UTF-8

Comment: @Filip, go to `Options->Under the hood->Change font and language settings->Languages`. There you will see a list of languages which are used when sending the request. If your Chrome is in English I suppose you will have `English (United States)` as first language there. This would mean that `.` is the decimal separator on the client. On the server you have `sv-SE` which uses `,` as separator. When you set the culture to `auto` in your web.config the server should pick `en-US` as well. To verify if this is the case inspect the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` on the server.